# How to properly drag element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, draggable, hammer.js

I'm trying to create a image cropper, that's based on a image inside a container box. The user should be able to drag or move the image and pinch to zoom.

Currently, I've been working in the drag functionality, but I find that's not working properly. When going from Top left and drag to Bottom right works more or less ok, but if I do try to drag from left to right or the inverse, the image keeps bouncing back to the initial drag position.

My code is really basic, where you can see that I just add to x or y the deltaY/X, which I seem would be more then enough ?

```
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var imgEl = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];

        Hammer(element).on("dragstart", function(event) {
            imgEl = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];

            y = parseFloat(imgEl.style.top) || 0;
            x = parseFloat(imgEl.style.top) || 0;
        });

        Hammer(element).on("drag", function(event) {

            imgEl.style.top = (y + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaY))+'px';
            imgEl.style.left = (x + parseFloat(event.gesture.deltaX))+'px';

        });
```

I've got a demo setup here: http://jsbin.com/kimes/4

- When testing I've been noticing that, when I drag from Bottom right to Top Left works fine!

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new mouse position to the dragging variable.

Comment: thanks for looking! Isn't that what I'm doing by doing the sum with x and y + event.gesture.deltaX/Y ? I'll have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry about taking you guys time, I had a typo:

```
        y = parseFloat(imgEl.style.top) || 0;
        x = parseFloat(imgEl.style.top) || 0;
```

Should be:

```
        y = parseFloat(imgEl.style.top) || 0;
        x = parseFloat(imgEl.style.left) || 0;
```